# What HTTP status code should I return that tells the browser to stay in the current page?

Tags: html, http, http-status-codes

I have a table with lots of generic link from a DB.

Now the customer wants to restrict certain types to be linked (or showed). Changing the page that makes the links is very hard, so I want to show some alert to user but would be ideal that the browser stays in the page, instead of navigation to an empty one and force the user o press back.

**Is there a HTTP status code that tells the browser to stay in the current page?**

Comment: See this earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654636/responding-so-the-browser-does-not-do-anything-is-it-possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try with `204 No Content`

See the [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> If the client is a user agent, it
>   SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to
>   be sent. This response is primarily
>   intended to allow input for actions to
>   take place without causing a change to
>   the user agent's active document view,
>   although any new or updated
>   metainformation SHOULD be applied to
>   the document currently in the user
>   agent's active view.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Now I have to find a way to notify the user because it swallows the javascript alert also.